# How do I replicate the red delete button from the Contacts application? (i.e. in a grouped TV Layout and such that it darkens when selected)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

As you see from the question, I want to do (aesthetically) EXACTLY what the red delete button in the contacts app does.

Now the issue is that it doesn't provide feedback when I press on it (namely become darker); it simply does its duty of popping up a UIAlertView to confirm the deletion (side note: I find this more appropriate than an ActionSheet for this case since I need to give a message to the user about the repercussions of deleting as well...).

What I have done is make a custom cell class, to characterize this button and manually gave it this design in IB.

Now assuming I can make a png file of a darker version of the button background, how could I make it such that that background shows when the button is pressed down.

I apologize in advance for any lack of clarity. If you don't get what I'm talking about, please go to the Contacts app and try pressing down the "Delete Contact" button. That's the aesthetic functionality I'm looking for.

Thanks,

-HT

Edit:
Got something that almost works. From the CustomTVCell.m:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state.
if (selected == YES)
    self.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_red_selected.png"]] autorelease];
else
    self.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_red.png"]] autorelease];
}
```

The only remaining issue is that it remains in the selected state even when I stopping pressing the cell.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a (BOOL bDark) to mark the status of backgroud image,that is whether you use the dark one or the light one.init bDark with NO.
in your tableview's cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method,if the bDark is YES, let the cell's background image be the dark one,else let it be the light one.
in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, you should change the bDark to YES,that is,once you pressed that cell,bDark should be set to YES; then you should let your tableview reloadData,then it rebuild the cells, and now, because bDark is YES, this cell will use the dark image as its backgroud.

Comment: Hmm, not sure how to access this "bDark". It doesn't appear to be a property of UITableViewCell. Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: Oh you mean something custom I would make.